# In Power BI create a table with ranges based on a list

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I am working in Power BI and I have data in a table that looks like presented in INPUT. I need to transform it to get ranges (as presented in GOAL). I was able to get the ranges for aggregated A and B and MIN, MAX values using simple visualization which is not excatly what I need. No idea how to **get ranges for different series of A, B separately**. Is this even doable in Power BI?

Note: with some help from you, I was able to make it work with Python but unfortunately it turned out that this needs to be done entirely in Power BI (without implementation of Python code).

I am stuck and I would be grateful for any suggestions that would get me started.

**INPUT**

| error | seq num |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 4 |
| A | 5 |
| A | 6 |
| A | 7 |
| A | 8 |
| B | 9 |
| B | 10 |
| B | 11 |
| A | 12 |
| A | 13 |
| A | 14 |
| B | 15 |
| B | 16 |
| B | 17 |
| B | 18 |
| B | 19 |
| B | 20 |
| B | 21 |

**GOAL**

I need two separate results, preferrably in tables but at this point I am open to any solutions.

**(1)**

| Cat | MIN | MAX |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 8 |
| A | 12 | 14 |
| B | 9 | 11 |
| B | 15 | 21 |

**(2)**

| Cat | ranges |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1-8; 12-14 |
| B | 9-11; 15-21 |

I am attaching an input table and pbix file where it is already loaded.
https://github.com/jarsonX/Temp_files

This is obviously a dummy data. In real-life the csv might have more columns and much more rows but I only need those two mentioned above. If you give me some advice or an example of how this could be solved, I'll try to figure out the rest on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what type of granularity you need to retain in your model but here is one way.

[image]

In PQ, you need to group and add the last parameter as groupkind.local. Full code.

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\Dav\Downloads\file.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=2, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"error", type text}, {"seq num", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"error"}, {{"Min", each List.Min([seq num]), type nullable number}, {"Max", each List.Max([seq num]), type nullable number}}, GroupKind.Local)
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Results in this table:

[image]

In powerbi, create a measure as follows.

```
Measure = CONCATENATEX(input_data, input_data[Min] &"-"& input_data[Max],";")
```

Add everything to a table.

[image]

Comment: With `GroupKind.Local`, it is crucial to apply correct sorting prior to grouping. I would do this explicitly in thr query instead of assuming order.  Great solution, David!

Comment: Agreed and good point.